# Filename filter for windows explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

*I'm not looking for a windows explorer alternative. I like it, and it does its job well.*

However, the one thing I'm missing from it, is the function to filter the filenames by a specified criteria. For example, `*visual*.pdf` would show me all files which are of PDF kind, and have the "visual" in their filename.

Does anyone perhaps know of a plugin/extension ... for windows explorer which enables this kind of thing ?

Comment: Just get and use Everything, it searches everything on your computer be name, indexes really fast, and is quick to launch

Comment: The command line supports exactly this, if you don't mind it.

Answer (score 2):

[StExtBar](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar) adds a toolbar to Windows Explorer. The right-hand field is used to filter the files. Type a string (part of the filename, or the extension) and you'll see only files matching this string. No support for "*" though.

It's a free addon.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that's the job of the Search button. Be wary of shell extensions, they can cause Explorer to crash (but at least it recovers itself these days).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, in XP and up. You have to setup the advanced search option and get rid of that stupid dog or paper clip. I wish there was a "shoot the dog" addon. You can search on title by type, size or date without much difficulty.

Comment: I'm aware of windows search. But that's not what I'm looking for in here.

Comment: I wrote up a How-To using Windows Search to filter on wildcards a few years ago http://mattlock.blogspot.com/2007/01/using-wildcards-in-windows-explorer.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of Windows, but if you don't want any third party tools, in Vista and 7, you can achieve this by typing *name* in the search in the top right box.

I know of no good tools that do this, and the built in one is far from perfect, but it does seem to work.

I just typed in *allo* and it came up with the correct files I would expect at the top, then random ones underneath - and no idea why it selected them.

Comment: Sorry about that - XPsp2

Answer (score 1):

[DMEXBar](http://www.simtel.net/product.php?url_fb_product_page=59298) seems to fulfill your demands, and more.
From the article [DMEXBar: brings the functionality of a dual pane file manager to Windows Explorer](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2008/02/06/dmexbar-brings-the-functionality-of-a-dual-pane-file-manager-to-windows-explorer/):

> **Filtering files by wildcard:** this can
>   be an extension or a string/substring
>   within the filenames. Enter the
>   filtering string in the box and choose
>   “filter”. What’s really cool is that
>   you can repeat the operation multiple
>   times.

This is an image of the selection dialog:

[image: image1]

This is an image of Windows Explorer with this add-on installed:

[image]

I've never used this program and take no responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

I think he was looking for something like this little shell extension:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/wildcardselect.aspx

The pity is it is NOT working on Windows 7 (I've been using that "proof of concept" for years). Very useful, for example, a common downloads directory which eventually you want to clean... lets select *visual*.pdf to a one folder, *.Zip to a different one, and University.* to another one. This extension allowed to, having only one explorer pane open, select the desired files, and drag them to the desired tree folder. Easy, comfortable, fast, lightweight, no extra apps, no extra bars...

Now i've installed 7 i'm looking for such a great utility (designed 9 years ago!)
That's why Im writing, just to help people still uses XP.